# IOS UIWebView: How to add listeners to DOM events?

Tags: ios, events, dom, uiwebview

How can I add listeners to DOM events in UIWebView? For example for the following html:

```
<button type="button" id="button1">Try it</button>
```

Is it possible to register a listener for a button click event in IOS application that loads html in UIWebView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with crafted url and UIWebViewDelegate methods.

First, to add event listener on button tag, you should execute javascript like below (after the page is loaded)

```
// In the UIWebViewDelegate
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (/* when the loaded url is the target */) {
        NSString *js = @"document.getElementById('button').click = function() { window.location = 'my-protocol://dummmy.com/maybe/some/data';}";
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
    }
}
```

We bind a click event on the button, and when it's clicked, it will trigger a request to webView.

And the next thing we gotta do is to intercept the request and do what you want in ObjC.

```
// In the UIWebViewDelegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (/* when the url of the request is the crafted url */) {
        // call your objc method...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! And BTW what is 'window.location' ? Looks like a DOM root, is it? Can I directly manipulate DOM using 'window.location'?

Comment: you can manipulate DOM directly with the "js" variable passed into the "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" method. For example, remove the page content: "document.write('');"

Comment: Is there a risk of this failing if the DOM node that IOS is looking for needs a few ms to be rendered by a client side library such as React/Vue ?

Comment: @EgistLi Is there a risk of this failing if the DOM node that IOS is looking for needs a few ms to be rendered by a client side library such as React/Vue ?

Comment: @timebandit I believe so. If you are working with something inside React/Vue, you need to somehow hook into the lifecycle of React/Vue. Or you can try using event delegation and bind button onclick event listener on `document` object if the button onClick event listener's event propagation is not stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Swift way to intercept when a Link is clicked in the `UIWebView`:

Get yourself a delegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate { //... }
```

And assign it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.delegate = self

        //...
}
```

Now we can use it to intercept:

```
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
            if (currentURL?.lowercased().range(of:"some/url") != nil) {
                webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = function() {window.location = 'injected://loadPDF1'; return false;}")
            }
    }

    // Sent before a web view begins loading a frame.
    func webView(_: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool{
        // intercept all injected page calls
        if (shouldStartLoadWith.url?.scheme == "injected") {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```