# How to make UIWebView interactive?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, user-input

I have a web page with some questions and answer options (MCQs) designed on UIWebView control where user will select the answer, I want retrieve that selected answer.

Please help me, how to obtain the user interaction value from UIWebView?

Comment: There's [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328519/ios-uiwebview-how-to-add-listeners-to-dom-events).

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: There's a [full blogpost](http://warmfuzzyapps.com/2011/08/fun-with-uiwebview/) about the method here which has some comments relating to the problems that might be encountered and possible fixes.